# Value not printed in checkbox when retrieving value using Django and MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have code that should retrieve the content to checkbox using the value from other dropdowns. So currently am able to get value of dropdown but not checkbox. I checked the name of column and all related things but everything is same as in database table. And was not able to find the reason why it is not working.

**index.html**

```
   <br>&emsp;<label for="sn">Server Names:</label>
            {% for n in result5 %}
                <input type="checkbox" id="Server1" name="Server1" value="{{n.servername}}">
                <label for="Server1"> {{n.servername}}</label>&emsp;&emsp;
                {% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Index(models.Model):
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    invid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    apptypeofpg1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customerofpg1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #TemplateName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    environmentofpg3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    patchconfigofpg3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['ServerDetails']:
            print("Hi")
            cursor5 = conn.cursor()
            cursor5.execute("select distinct(servername) from PatchingUI.dbo.mainDetails WHERE abc= '"+abc+"' and qwe ='"+qwe+"' and chs= '"+chs+"'; ")
            result5 = cursor5.fetchall()
            print(result5)
```

But I am able to print contents in `views.py`. It shows the result of the query in `views.py`. But not in the HTML page. I am not able to understand what is the reason why.

Comment: Your query is open to SQL injection, **use parameters for the values, not interpolation**

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `result5` in the `context` dictionary from your view, so that template can have access to it:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'result5': result5})
```